# Is there a better way to write this SQL query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm looking to return the row with biggest create_dt. This works fine, however I would like to know if there is a more proper way of doing this?

```
select * from 
table1 
where job_no='101047' 
and 
create_dt in
     (select max(create_dt) from    
      table1 where job_no='101047')
```

Comment: You don't mention which DB technology.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

How about:

```
Select top 1 *
from table1
where job_no = '101047'
order by create_dt desc
```

Comment: Select top 1 * from table 1 where job_no = '101047' order by create_dt desc

Comment: thanks. Looks like I corrected before you had a chance to correct me. :)

Comment: +1 I like this, I can get the min date by using asc. Thanks sir. There's just something about nested queries I don't like.

Answer (score 4):

your query will return more than one value if there is more than one row of create_dt
where job_no = '101047'

This will work better

```
 Select top 1 * from table1 
 where job_no='101047'   
 order by create_dt desc
```